# Subversive Connector Discovery is not opening in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

Subversive Connector Discovery is not opening in Eclipse Kepler 64 (Ubuntu 13.04 64). So, I've installed SVNKit 1.7.9 + JNA Library 3.4.0 connector from directly http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x, but the connector is not appearing in

> Window >> Preferences >> Team >> SVN >> SVN Connector (tab).

When I tried add a new repository in "SVN Repository Exploring" view, I'm getting this:

> SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished
>   with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot
>   be loaded. If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if
>   binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion
>   connector from the plug-in connectors update site. If connectors
>   already installed then you can change the selected one at:
>   Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector. Selected SVN connector
>   library is not available or cannot be loaded. If you selected native
>   JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install
>   and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors
>   update site. If connectors already installed then you can change the
>   selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.

I've installed Oracle Java 8, subversion 1.7.5 and libsvn-java in my Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed. I just had installed incompatible SVN connector.